# I need to reverse the polarity of a circuit for a slave clock with a simple on off switch momentarily once a minute

Tags: switches

I need to reverse the polarity of the power to a slave clock once a minute with the simple single pole switch in a master clock. A reversing DPDT relay does not work as the power needs to be off between each reverse switching action?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a latching DPDT relay, it maintains the position last selected without power. You just pulse it and it will toggle, others have two coils and you select the one you want to latch.